# What did White Fang tell Kakashi about Might Guy in episode 421?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language

In episode 421, White Fang and Kakashi meets Maito Dai and Might Guy. Kakashi kind of despises Might Guy because he didnt get into the Academy. After that, Might Guy smiles, makes a thumb up with his hand, and tells him "thanks for the support!".

Then, I've seen 2 translations for what White Fang said to Kakashi next. In one of them, he tells Kakashi that "at that pace, that kid is going to surpass you". That's the one I liked better because it sounded like with that attitude Might Guy was going to surpass Kakashi. Then, there is another translation (that might be the right one) which said "at the rate that kid is training, that boy is going to be stronger than you". This sounds like a more realistic translation of what he could say, but I really dont know if it's right.

Which is the most accurate translation? What did White Fang actually say to Kakashi about Might Guy? This is the segment I'm talking about, [Kakashi and His Father - Konoha's White Fang Meets Might Guy for the First Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVofahLwHi0)

Comment: pretty sure it depends on what platform you watch on, but i got "At the rate he's training, that boy is going to surpass you."

Comment: The meaning is same.

Comment: @Jdeep ye, but he wants to which one is more accurate/official